# How to copy all column data from one excel to another excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy all column data from column **range A:AU** of one excel to another excel in same range of column **A:AU** in which i have written the code .

Both excel are placed at different locations in my computer and i have written my vba code in the excel where i want to paste data,  not in the excel from where i am copying the data.

name of excel from where i am copying the data is **"EXRData_08.01.2018.xlsx"**  and sheet name is **"EXR_extract_EX"**

& the name of excel where i want to paste the data and where i have written my vba code is **"UnattendedData.xlsm"** and sheet name is **"RawData"** .

I am trying to copy entire column content from **range A:AU** from first excel and paste it into same **range of A:AU** in another excel where code is present but i am getting error and it is not running . kindly help me regarding this.

below is my code-

```
Sub panos()
  Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, N As Long

  Workbooks.Open "\01_Tool\Data\EXRData_08.01.2018.xlsx"
  N = Sheets("EXR_extract_EX").Cells(Rows.Count, "A:AU").End(xlUp).Row
  Set r1 = Sheets("EXR_extract_EX").Range("A:AU" & N)

  Workbooks.Open "_Master\Saurabh\UnattendedData.xlsm"
  Set r2 = Sheets("RawData").Range("A:AU")

  r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get and in which line?

Comment: i got error here onwards- N = Sheets("EXR_extract_EX").Cells(Rows.Count, "A:AU").End(xlUp).Row
  Set r1 = Sheets("EXR_extract_EX").Range("A:AU" & N)      --object  defined error.  @Peh

Comment: `Range("A:AU" & N)` is not a valid range it should be either `Range("A:AU")` for the full column or something like `Range("A" & N & ":AU" & N)`. I also recommend to use the full file path in `Workbooks.Open` and specify the workbook for Sheets otherwise you will run into issues. Also the `UnattendedData.xlsm` doesn't need to be opened, because this is already opened as you run the code from this file as you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don'n need to open `UnattendedData.xlsm`. If this is the workbook you run the code from it is already opened.
2. Use the full path for `Workbooks.Open` otherwise you will run into issues.
3. Use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` whenever possible. `Sheets` also contains charts etc.
4. If you use `Worksheets` or `Sheets` always specify the workbook like `wb.Worksheets(…)`. Otherwise Excel guesses a workbook and might fail.

The actual issue in your code is that `Range("A:AU" & N)` is no valid range. E.g. for `N=15` this results in `"A:AU15"` which is invalid. It should be either `"A15:AU15"` or `"A:AU"`.

I doubt there is a big advantage in performance using one or the other if the rest of the column is empty anyway, so I would just copy the whole columns.

---

Example:

```
Option Explicit 'make sure all variables have to be declared correctly

Public Sub CopyRanges()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\YOUR_FULL_PATH_HERE\01_Tool\Data\EXRData_08.01.2018.xlsx")

    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Set shtSource = wb.Worksheets("EXR_extract_EX")
                   '^-- Always specify a wb for a sheet

    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    Set shtDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")
                         '^-- here we specify the workbook we are running  the code in
    'copy the ranges
    shtSource.Range("A:AU").Copy shtDestination.Range("A:AU")

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'don't forget to close the workbook
End Sub
```

Note that if you need the path relative to the path of `ThisWorkbook` you can use something like

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\01_Tool\Data\EXRData_08.01.2018.xlsx"
```

If it is in the same base path but different sub folders you could walk backwards with `\..\` to get out of the subfolders like

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\..\01_Tool\Data\EXRData_08.01.2018.xlsx"
```